# dl4j does not contain text and models modules

Tags: java, neural-network, nlp, deeplearning4j

In my project, I need to use the Word2Vec model. I decide to use dl4j for this. I load all dependencies, but there are no modules such as deeplearning4j.text and deeplearning4j.models

I tried to change the version of dl4j from beta5 to 4 and 3 but the problem still here
I even tried download jar files of dl4j but it didn't help too

Comment: Can you show your code to point out where the problem is (github link would be great). What dependencies did you defined. Maybe the examples at the dl4j github repo helps: https://github.com/eclipse/deeplearning4j-examples/tree/master/dl4j-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's deeplearning4j.nlp module and corresponding submodules like deeplearning4j.nlp.uima for example